# Initial proof method to consume all incoming facts

Tags: isabelle

Assume I have a goal `A ⟹ B ⟹ C ⟹ G` The goal is unwieldy (generated from some proof obligation), and it appears (in similar shape) several times in my development.

So I create a lemma `foo` to simplify the goal, of the shape `A ⟹ C ⟹ (P ⟹ Q) ⟹ G`.

I’d like to be able to write

```
case goal42
  thus ?case
  proof (rule foo)
    assume P
    show Q sorry
  qed
```

but this fails, because `foo` does not use `B`. What works is

```
case goal42
  thus ?case
    apply -
    apply (erule (1) eqvt_lam_case)
    proof-
    assume P
    show Q sorry
  qed
```

but this style of opening a `proof` in the middle of an apply script is considered bad practice.

Is there a method similar to `rule` that is a bit smarter in matching the incoming facts against the hypothesis of the rule? Ideally it reads a `consumes 2` parameter on `foo` to figure out how many hypothesis should match.

Answer (score 2):

The method `rule` is very picky about which facts are chained in. Its precursors `intro` and `elim` do not complain if chained-in facts do not fit; `intro` does not match against them at all. `elim ...` roughly corresponds to `apply - apply(erule ...)+`, so this might approximate what you are looking for. But I do not know of a way to tell `elim` to match multiple assumptions, and there `elim` tries to apply the given rules as long as possible, which might not be what you want.

However, since you open an Isar proof for the remaining goal anyway, you can rearrange your proof and avoid the issue.

```
case goal42
{ assume P
  show Q sorry }
with goal42 show ?case by-(erule (2) eqvt_lam_case)
```

Comment: I should like to add that `rule_tac` works pretty much like `rule`, but does not require assumptions to be chained in the right order (but also doesn't use them, as far as I know). I rarely use it, but it comes in handy sometimes.